# How do you make a column in the datagridview that is a checkbox populate a checkbox on an update form?

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox, datagridview

So one of my tables in the database I'm using has a few different checkbox columns that are information about the customer. Like one is if they are foreign or not or like a few yes or no questions. I made my form that has a bunch of text boxes that will populate themselves when you select a record.

I need the checkboxes to also populate but I do not know the syntax

I've tried looking up the solution but everything I found is about selecting a record by using a checkbox not getting a checkbox to fill itself in if it's checked or not on the table itself.

The code I'm using for the `TextBox`es is a row index methods that use this to populate the normal textboxes

```
txtboxFirstName.Text = row.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
txtboxLastName.Text = row.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
```

For the checkbox, I would imagine its something like
`ckboxForeignCust.Checked = row.Cells["ForesignCust"]` but I do not know how to finish that line of code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Getting UI controls to "fill itself in" is called *data binding*.  Gobs written on the topic

Comment: try: `ckboxForeignCust.Checked = (bool)row.Cells["ForesignCust"].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sql?

Checkbox columns are simple true or false, when you use DataReader.fill(datatable); and set datagrid.datasource = datatables; all boolean columns that you have inside your database, will turn into checkbox columns inside the datagridview.

Comment: Yeah i have a sql database that is feeding into the datagridview. The checkboxes show up in the datagridview but I want to bind this checkbox for updating the record if need be. When you type in a customer name right now every piece of information will populate into the text boxes but the checkboxes stay blank because i cant figure out how to bind them

Comment: How you're feeding the datagridview? manually? if you are using the method above, .fill(datatable), you dont need to bind the checkbox. 

If i get your problem, when you type any customer name, the grid will show all stored infos except the check boxes, right,?